# More current in non-inverter comparator hysteresis using a photoresistor

Tags: voltage, led, current, comparator, photoresistor

I'm doing a small circuit where I need automatic LED's to turn ON in a low light environment. So I decided to use a photoresistor (more light less resistance) connected to a non-inverter hysteresis comparator (I used hysteresis for a more controlled light detecting range) and in the OpAmp (TL084CN) output I connected the LEDs. The supply voltage in the IC(TL084CN) is +10V and -10V because I'm using a battery cell to make this circuit portable.[image: Circuit Diagram]

As you can see in the circuit diagram I connected 16 LEDs in parallel in the OpAmp output. The issue is: I connected only one LED at first and it was an OK brightness, I measured the current and it was about 23mA. Now you can imagine 23mA divided by 16 LEDs, the brightness is almost 0 (still brights but poorly).

I want to find a solution to give more current to the LEDs not disturbing the comparator circuit output.

PD: Forgot to mention that this circuit is connected to a 24.7V battery that is connected to a step-down circuit that outputs 10V and then to a voltage inverter to get that -10V to the supply voltage. The step-down I used has a 1A max output so maybe I need to get that current directly from the battery (I do not have another step-down)

Comment: You don't need an opamp for this. Do you really want one? I think you are probably going to too much effort to create dual rails, etc. Things could be a lot less complicated. But then I don't have your fuller information about where you are headed, either. So it may just be me. Also, your opamp isn't going to drive LEDs like that.

Comment: If you'd have used an LM324 op-amp you wouldn't need a negative 10 volt supply and you could connect the op-amp directly to 24.7 volts and 0 volts saving you on a regulator as well. @jonk - it's not just you dude!!

Comment: What does the LM324 datasheet say about maximum current? What does 16 LEDs need to illuminate? May want to add a driver to output of the opamp.

Comment: @jonk I don't need an OpAmp for this, but it was recommended to have hysteresis, and this is the only circuit I know with that, so I thought I could use this one. But I'm open to OpAmp-free circuit suggestions

Comment: @Bikke21 You only need a couple of BJTs and that includes the hysteresis. It will work directly with the 24.7 V, too. And there are at least three ways to get it done. However, that still leaves the driver for the LEDs. That's NOT included when I say "2 BJTs."